# creating one string from two in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Is there any way to add one string to the end of another in python? e.g.

String1 = 'A'
String2 = 'B'

and i want String3 == 'AB'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String concatenation in python is straightforward

```
a = "A"
b = "B"
c = a + b
print c

> AB
```

I benchmarked the three operations, performing 1m of each:

```
c = a + b
c = '%s%s' % (a,b)
c = "{0}{1}".format(a, b)
```

And the results are:

```
+:  0.232225275772
%s: 0.42436670365
{}: 0.683854960343
```

Even with 500 character strings, + is still fastest by far. My [script is on ideone](https://ideone.com/Gde9C) and the results (for 500 char strings) are:

```
+: 0.82
%s: 1.54
{}: 2.03
```

Comment: And I always thought string concatenation with + sign was slow. Maybe because the strings are too short?

Comment: Maybe, I've uploaded my script to Ideone, where the results are even more pronounced: http://ideone.com/a6JMi

Comment: I did not know .format method was slower than % method of formatting. I thought .format was the preferred method. Is it always slower?

Comment: Well for everything up to 500 character strings, yes. You can tweak my script to run further tests if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the simplest version: `String3 = String1 + String2` or the format operator (deprecated in python3): `String3 = '%s%s' % (String1, String2)`

Comment: Since it's explicitly tagged python-3.x I'd remove that second option.

Comment: @fredley, I read % would not be removed anytime soon. In the new python 3.2 it stays.

Comment: For Python 3, you can use `String3 = "{0}{1}".format(String1, String2)`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the + operator concatenates strings:

```
>>> String3 = String1 + String2
>>> String3
   'AB'
```

This is the simplest way and usually it's the right choice. However, sometimes you might need a more [efficient string concatenation](http://skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/).

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity when speed doesn't matter, you can't beat the ease of `c=a+b`.  If speed does matter (because you're making a large number of successive concatenations, for example), `str.join()` [can be a little more efficient (code at ideone)](https://ideone.com/i2VzX).

```
+: 2.51

''.join([a,...z]): 0.2

append(): 2.05
```

From what I can tell, if you are making successive concatenations without touching the intermediate product, I'm better off appending each addition to a list, then joining everything at once.  For the single concatenation case, `a+b` is still faster than `a.join(b)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out str.join():

```
>>>s1='a'
>>>s2='b'
>>>s3=''.join((s1,s2))
>>>s3
'ab'
```

also if you write:

```
>>>s3='WhatEver'.join((s1,s2))
>>>s3
'aWhatEverb'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code for string concatenation:
`

```
String1 = "a"
String2 = "b"
String3 = String1 + String2
#String 3 would be ab
```

`
You can add more than two string variables into one string variable.

Comment: What do you mean?