# Tell python to write something at every line

Tags: python, python-3.x, line, each, addition

Thanks the help of this forum, i'm finally arrived at this python3 code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'PreviewTooltip'}):
    links = (tag.get('href'))
    print (links)
```

It prints all the links of topics in the webpage: https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/
But the last thing that I need is: how to tell python to write ad every line, first the "threads" word, the other part of the link? (https://www.inforge.net/xi/)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us the expected output at least...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python) the base url with each link.

Try this code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")

base = 'https://www.inforge.net/xi/'

for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'PreviewTooltip'}):
    links = (tag.get('href'))
    full_url = base + links
    print (full_url)
```

Output:

> https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-23h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455661/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-11h11-pm.455660/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-22h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455656/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-9h45-pm.455655/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-18h30-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455651/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-6h25-pm.455650/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-13h00-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455634/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-1h00-pm.455633/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-09h15-am-update-24-24-good-socks.455631/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-8h00-am.455627/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-01h35-am-update-24-24-good-socks.455614/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-23h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455610/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-20h15-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455601/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-8h00-pm.455596/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-15h10-pm-update-24-24-good-socks.455588/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-1h25-pm.455587/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-10h45-am-update-24-24-good-socks.455585/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-10h40-am.455584/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/vn5socks-net-auto-update-24-7-good-socks-7h30-am.455583/
>   https://www.inforge.net/xi/threads/dichvusocks-us-01h40-am-update-24-24-good-socks.455569/

Comment: oh... i'm so stupid! i though that if I had done it, it'd added just to the first line.. but it was very easy.. thanks!