# Removing newline characters in a txt files

Tags: python

I'm doing Euler Problems and am at [problem #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) and wanted to just copy this huge 1000-digit number to a numberToProblem8.txt file and then just read it into my script but I can't find a good way to remove newlines from it. With that code:

```
hugeNumberAsStr = ''

with open('numberToProblem8.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        aSingleLine = line.strip()
        hugeNumberAsStr.join(aSingleLine)

print(hugeNumberAsStr)
```

Im using print() to only check if it works and well, it doesnt. It doesnt print out anything. What's wrong with my code? I remove all the trash with strip() and then use join() to add that cleaned line into hugeNumberAsStr (need a string to join those lines, gonna use int() later on) and its repeated for all the lines. 
[Here is the .txt file with a number in it.](https://gist.github.com/doublemc/cd7c5a96dbf6065f1215530b4a22fb11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
hugeNumberAsStr = open('numberToProblem8.txt').read()
hugeNumberAsStr = hugeNumberAsStr.strip().replace('\n', '')
```

Or even:

```
hugeNumberAsStr = ''.join([d for d in hugeNumberAsStr if d.isdigit()])
```

I was able to simplify it to the following to get the number from that file:

```
>>> int(open('numberToProblem8.txt').read().replace('\n',''))
731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511125406987471585238630507156932909632952274430435576689664895044524452316173185640309871112172238311362229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749303589072962904915604407723907138105158593079608667017242712188399879790879227492190169972088809377665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243525849077116705560136048395864467063244157221553975369781797784617406495514929086256932197846862248283972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474821663704844031998900088952434506585412275886668811642717147992444292823086346567481391912316282458617866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042242190226710556263211111093705442175069416589604080719840385096245544
```

Comment: strip() removes `\n`

Comment: @HaifengZhang no these are `\n` in the middle of it. Like: `>>> x='1234\n234\n'
>>> x.strip()
'1234\n234'`

Comment: Do I need to close reading this file? Or it closes itself in this case? I know that when I use with open() as f: it closes itself but am not sure in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `hugeNumberAsStr += aSingleLine` instead of `hugeNumberAsStr.join(..)`

`str.join()` joins the passed iterator and return the string value joined by `str`. It doesn't update the value of `hugeNumberAsStr` as you think. You want to create a new string with removed `\n`. You need to store these values in new string. For that you need append the content to the string

Comment: @doublemc `+=` will add the string to the previous part. `join` is more used to combine together existing string elements in a list or other similar object.

Comment: @doublemc: Check edit. Feel free to ask in case of more doubt. I will suggest to go through the document once. You will get more information

Comment: I get it now. If I wanted to I could use append() but according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171382/7227475  += is better and I will be using this one in situations like this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The join method for strings simply takes an iterable object and concatenates each part together.  It then returns the resulting concatenated string.  As stated in help(str.join):

join(...)
    S.join(iterable) -> str

```
Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
iterable.  The separator between elements is S.
```

Thus the join method really does not do what you want.
The concatenation line should be more like:

```
hugeNumberAsString += aSingleLine
```

Or even:

```
hugeNumberAsString += line.strip()
```

Which gets rid of the extra line of code doing the strip.