# Python Error with appending string to a file, how do I add it correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, fwrite

I am building a function that opens a file, calculates the sum of integers on different lines, and appends the file with a new string 'Total=sum' on a new line. I am getting error: can't assign to operator on my final value. This is not a duplicate being that I edited the way the duplicate suggestion did and it is still throwing an error. Also, I need to KEEP THE TOTAL, after every iteration.

Here is my function:

```
def append_total(filename):
    total=0
    with open(filename) as contents:
        for line in contents:
            if line.isdigit():
                total+=int(line)
            else:
                total=0
    final='Total:'+total+end='\n'
    contents.write(final)
    return
```

Comment: You can't have keyword arguments to a tuple literal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Comment: You should paste the exact error message as well!

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you elaborate? I'm new to this so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: `final = ('Total:', total, '\n')` would create a tuple, in the same way that `final = ['Total:', total, '\n']` would create a list. It's a *literal* form of that container. It cannot take a keyword argument like `end=`.

Comment: after every non-digit line `total` will be set to zero, previously accumulated sum will be lost, is it a desired behavior?

Comment: No. I want to keep the total @AzatIbrakov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

1) statement

```
final = ('Total:', total, end='\n')
```

has invalid syntax and looks like you just removed `print` and replaced it with assignment to `final`. If you want to make string just write something like

```
final = 'Total:' + str(total) + '\n'
```

more info about string concatenation at [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common)

2) you are trying to write in file that was not opened in write mode and furthermore is closed after you leave `with` statement block. If you want to append a line in the end of existing file you can write

```
with open(filename, mode='a') as contents:
    contents.write(final)
```

more info about `open` at [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

3) you need to remove newline symbols from lines to make `str.isdigit` work as expected, we can do this by using [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method

```
line.strip().isdigit()
```

4) your accumulated `total` will be lost in cases when any line is not a digit-like, we can save it from zeroing just by removing `else` block

Finally your function will be like

```
def append_total(filename):
    total = 0
    with open(filename) as contents:
        for line in contents:
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            if stripped_line.isdigit():
                total += int(stripped_line)
    final = 'Total:' + str(total) + '\n'
    with open(filename, mode='a') as contents:
        contents.write(final)
```

(you don't need to explicitly return in the end of every function)

Comment: we need to append at the end of the file, no reading required, what's the problem?

Comment: no problem. well, there are still problems with your version of the code, but i only wanted to clarify, that `a` is write-only.

Comment: which problems?

Comment: `a` is write-only, `r+`/`a+` would be read/write. `w+` would also truncate the file.

Comment: we are making single write operation, why do we need to open in both `read`/`write` modes?

Comment: you don't. i never said you do.

Answer (score 1):

hey it seems to me that you have two "error" in your code:

first you try to write in a close file

second you don't open the file for writting or adding

`def append_total(filename):
    total=0
    with open(filename) as contents:
        for line in contents:
            if line.isdigit():
                total+=int(line)
            else:
                total=0
    with open (filename, 'a') as contents: # a for append w for write
        contents.write('Total:{}\n'.format(total))`

`
In python when a function return nothing you can spare the return statement
Or if you want to be explicit say return None.

sorry didn't read all the comment but you also have a problem with total
I updated my answer

Comment: This still yields the error. The issue is with final.

Comment: I just change it.

Comment: So now it's giving True or False, which is not what was wanted.

Comment: please could you develop? is it appending True False to your file? I don't know what the purpose of the script but may be you have a type and want to make +=0 or continue when line is not a digit

Comment: It needs to return none after appending final to the file

Comment: ok so you can in this case use as you were doing: `return` / or `return None` which is my preference as explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: there is no way for this function to return `True` or `False` because it returns `None` by default at the end of the execution

Answer (score 1):

There are several Problems with your script:

```
final=('Total:', total, end='\n')
```

The syntax error comes from `end='\n'`. You probably rewrote a `print()` line, but you cannot use that syntax when creating a tuple (which is what you do now).

A better version would be:

```
final = 'Total:' + total + '\n'
```

but that would fail, because you cannot "add" a string and an int.

You could use `int(total)`, but using the `format` method would be even better:

```
final = 'Total: {}\n'.format(total)
```

The next problem is, that you try to write to the file *after* the `with` block, which will lead to another error. Move the last two lines into the block as well:

```
def append_total(filename):
    total = 0
    with open(filename) as contents:
        for line in contents:
            if line.isdigit():
                total += int(line)
            else:
                total = 0

    final = 'Total: {}\n'.format(total)
    contents.write(final)
```

This will still fail, because by default, files are opened read-only. You have to give `open()` a mode:

```
with open('blah.txt', 'r+') as contents:
```

will open the file read/writable and writes will be appended to the end (because you read the whole file before writing).

Further: the total will never be updated, because `line` contains a `'\n'` character at the end, and `'1\n'.isdigit()` will return False. You need to `strip()` the line before you use it:

```
line.strip().isdigit():
```

I also got rid of the final `return`, which is implicitely added by Python.