# How do I partially make a string but not complete it? PYTHON

Tags: python

How do I partially make a string in Python? I am working on a for loop that appends a string over multiple reruns. Once a string is made it can't be changed. How do I make it so it is partially finished but the code will come back later and finish it?

Comment: Sure it can be changed... What's your example code that's not working?

Comment: You either are not explaining your problem correctly or you have a misconception about assigning objects (including strings) to variables.  It always helps to provide an example of what you are trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The string is immutable, so when you change it, python just makes a new string with your additions. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: What are you really asking about? If you really feel the need to not concat in a for loop then just append items to a list and then join that list when you are done but in most cases using `+=` should be just fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a string to another with the `+` operator

Code :

```
String = "start"
String = String + "end"
print String
```

Output :

```
"startend"
```