# Space in Random List Generated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a random list of names from a from a bigger list of names. The problem is, there is no space between the names that are generated. I cannot understand how to put space. Here's my code

```
import random

final_list = ""

a=0

sss = ("John","Adam","Sara","Lory","Dick","Popeye")

while a<7:

    x = random.choice(sss)

    final_list += x

    a += 1

print (final_list)
```

---

The result is something like this:
SaraAdamDickPopeyeSaraPopeyeLory

How can I add space between the names? Also, can anyone suggest a shorter way to do this code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python) may be helpful.  Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional empty empty string at the original concatenation:

```
x = random.choice(sss)
final_list += " "+x if final_list else x
a += 1
```

Or, more precisely, use `' '.join` in list comprehension:

```
sss = ("John","Adam","Sara","Lory","Dick","Popeye")
final_string = ' '.join(random.choice(sss) for i in range(7))
```

Comment: this will not behave exactly right as a space will be appended before first name as well

Answer (score 0):

To avoid leading or trailing spaces, check if length of `final_list` is already greater than zero.

```
import random

final_list = ""
a=0
sss = ("John","Adam","Sara","Lory","Dick","Popeye")
while a<7:
    x = random.choice(sss)
    final_list = final_list + " " + x if len(final_list) > 0 else x
    a += 1
print (final_list)
```

If you don't want explicit checking, you can make use of [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) function to remove leading and trailing spaces after you construct the `final_list`.