# is it possible to do string array in python3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

I'm a beginner in python, I want to create a string array in python. Is it possible.

we can create integer array like this,

```
import array as arr
vals = arr.array('i',[8,3,1,5,9,2])

#vals = arr.array('u',['a','e','i','o','u'])
'''
u means unicode character.
'''

print ("The new created array is : ",end="\n") 
for val in vals: 
    print (val, end=' ')
```

like the above is possible to create the string array?

```
import array as arr

vals = arr.array('u', ['TATA Motors','Maruti Suzuki','Hindustan Motors Limited','Ashok Leyland','Mahindra & Chinkara Motors','Opel','Eicher Motors'])

print ("The new created array is : ",end="\n") 
for i in range (0, len(vals)): 
   print (vals[i], end=' ')
```

is this possible? if any other possible ways please help me.

Comment: you may instead want to just use the list directly. Not sure if you realised that or not.

Comment: `array` is meant to be used for 'basic values: characters, integers, floating point numbers.', as stated in the doc. So, no, it isn't a structure you can use for strings, that can have any possible size. What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh list is possible. Any possible way for array

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Okay thank you!

Comment: How do you think `array` is different from `list`?

Comment: I think array is based type dependent, but list is not. we can create a list like      temp_list = ['a','value','2019']

Comment: **Why** do you want to use an `array.array` instead of a `list`? What is the use-case? What is the advantage over `list`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just for the knowledge, I try to create one but I failed. To know have any possible ways for the creation of string array.

Comment: @AkhilKrishnan do you understand the purpose of the `array.array` type? It does not hold Python types. `str` is a python type. *Why not use a list*?

Comment: Now yes. @juanpa.arrivillaga can you explain clearly. or can you refer any material for that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you!

Comment: If you are a beginning in Python, you shouldn't be concerned with the `array` module. It is for very specific use-cases. You need to understand the *why* at the same times as the *how*. And that has to come before "is arbitrary X possible". You **almost certainly** need to just use a `list`

Comment: Okay @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: See the [+50] answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46997389/5378816