# passing two numbers as inputs and joining them together into a single string

Tags: python

I am very new to the coding world and stuck on this issue.I am attempting to pass two numbers as inputs and join them together into a single string. The problem I am encountering is that my code performs an addition function rather than combining the numbers.
my code is below with the results after.

```
import sys

number1 = int(sys.argv[1])
number2 = int(sys.argv[2])

newnumber = number1 + number2
print(newnumber)
```

> Program Failed for Input: 123 456 Expected Output: 123456 Your Program
>   Output: 579

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting the input to `int`, so obvisouly Python will perform integer addition.

Don't convert the input to `int`. This way Python will perform string concatenation.

```
import sys

number1 = sys.argv[1]  # no conversion to int
number2 = sys.argv[2]  # no conversion to int

newnumber = number1 + number2
print(newnumber)
```