# How to make one global variable from a for loop

Tags: python

So I have a for loop that when printing within the for loop prints exactly what I want since it prints for each line of the txt file. However I want to make all of those printed lines into one variable for use later on in the code.

This is for a scheduling program which I want to be able read from a txt file so that users can edit it through GUI. However since it is a loop, defining it, then printing outside of the loop obviously only prints the last line and I cant figure out a way around it.

```
with open('schedule.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c = line.split(',')
        print('schedule.every().{}.at("{}").do(job, "{}")'.format(a, b, c))
```

Output is what I want however I cannot define the whole thing as one variable as needed.

Comment: Either make a list to hold all of the strings you are printing which you can append to in each iteration of the loop or you can have a string variable which ```+=``` the string you are printing.

Comment: See this answer on comparing string concatenation performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169859/1008938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
code = []
with open('schedule.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c = line.split(',')
        code.append('schedule.every().{}.at("{}").do(job, "{}")'.format(a, b, c))
```

Now `code` is a list of strings. Then you can join them together in a single string like this:

```
python_code = ";".join(code)
```

Another way which may be easier to read is to define `code = ""` and then append to it in the loop:

```
code += 'schedule.every().{}.at("{}").do(job, "{}");'.format(a, b, c)
```

Then you won't need to `join` anything, but the output will have an unnecessary semicolon as the last character, which is still valid, but a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate an empty list before you open the file. Append the variables `a`, `b` and `c` to the list as you read them. This would give you a list of lists containing what you need.

```
variables = []
with open('schedule.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a,b,c = line.split(',')
        variables.append([a, b, c])

print(variables)
```