# Why does this for-loop return an empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, return

This is what i currently have:

```
messages = {
  "Placeholder": 0,
  "1": 48,
  "2": 4,
  "3": 31,
  "4": 2
}

def pls():


    messages_sorted = sorted(messages, key=messages.get, reverse=True)

    for i in range(10):
        output = []
        try:
            currp = str(messages_sorted[i])
            if currp == "Placeholder":
                print("PLACEHOLDER DETECTED")
                return output
            currpp = messages[currp]
            output.append(f"{currp} has {currpp} and is Place {i+1}")
            print(output)

        except IndexError:
            print("Index error")

        except:
            print("some other error")
    
    return output

output = pls()
output = str(output)
output = output.replace("['", "")
output = output.replace("']", "")
print(output)
```

I already used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399617/how-to-make-one-global-variable-from-a-for-loop)'s Answer to make the different Outputs one List, however when i run it, it returns an empty List. When i remove the following part:

```
if currp == "Placeholder":
            print("PLACEHOLDER DETECTED")
            return output
```

I just get a bunch of Index Errors. The

```
print(output)
```

inside the for-loop gets me exactly what i need in the Console (as different strings), however i cant return it as a List or variable . How can i do that?

Comment: `output = []` should be placed *outside* the loop. Otherwise each iteration you will clear the list. Not to mention that the `return output` after the loop ends will fail as there's no `output` variable at that point.

Comment: Did you mean to move: `output = []` to the line before the `for` loop?

Comment: Also thanks to both of you

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: btw the `return output` cannot fail since the `for` loop is guaranteed to run at least once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `output=[]` is inside your for loop. So at each iteration, its value is reinitialized, you should try again with `output=[]` before the for loop

Comment: I cant belive i didnt see this, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your `output` list is empty when you return it because every time the `for loop` restarts you reset the list.

Your code should look like this:

```
  messages = {
  "Placeholder": 0,
  "1": 48,
  "2": 4,
  "3": 31,
  "4": 2
             }

def pls():
    messages_sorted = sorted(messages, key=messages.get, reverse=True)
    output = []
    for i in range(10):
        
        try:
            currp = str(messages_sorted[i])
            if currp == "Placeholder":
                print("PLACEHOLDER DETECTED")
                return output
            currpp = messages[currp]
            output.append(f"{currp} has {currpp} and is Place {i+1}")
            print(output)

        except IndexError:
            print("Index error")

        except:
            print("some other error")
    
    return output

output = pls()
output = str(output)
output = output.replace("['", "")
output = output.replace("']", "")
print(output)
```