# Need help some with simple python find in strings

Tags: python, selenium, pdf

I'm a newbie coder and I need some help with the `xxx.find` usages...

**Summary**

I am doing a web automation project with selenium. 
This python project's main goal is

**Step 1**. To login into my school's LMS website automatically with provided username and password

**Step 2**. Get the page_source of a given website URL which my school hosts all the assignment PDF files

**Step 3**. Do a matching search of PDF **viewer** links on the page_source string

**Step 4**. Navigate to the matching PDF **viewer** URL and get the page_source again

**Step 5**. Search for `var DEFAULT_URL = '/icom/files/b729266c557f5f7108894ade1668d55a.pdf'` or relevant links which is the link that my school server hosts the pdf file

**Step 6**. Get the value `/icom/files/xxxxxx.pdf` and combine with a header like `www.icom.org.cn/` so they become `www.icom.org.cn/icom/files/xxxx.pdf`

**Step 7**. Then perform a `wget` command or something to get the pdf file.

**The problem now**

I somehow got the login automation correctly but now stuck at the page_source matching process but somehow stuck at **Step 3**

After getting onto the website URL where my school **hosts** all PDF assignment.

I ran a `sauce = driver.pages_source` and I am trying to match it by

```
word = ("/icom/faculty/viewer/?id")
print(sauce.find(word))
```

But the output of the find is `5122`

I would like that the `str.find` usage to match and **list** up all matching result and output the values in lines but not numbers...

So ... how can I do that? I searched up the internet for this but still isn't too informative to me. Sorry that I'm just a beginner in programming and I don't speak English too well. Thank you in advance.

By the way, a problem popped out in my mind.

If I was able to match up the value in **Step 3**. How can I code it to include extra value inside of the **PDF viewer link**?

Because the full link will be like this:

`/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1260&type=2` For English assignment

`/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1254&type=2` For Mathematics assignment

`/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=775&type=2` For assignment covers etc

The extra value `id=xxxx` always will be different. So... how can I code it to match up and list out all **matching result + extra value**?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

**Exact example of the page_source**

```
  </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=FP102-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">FP102-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">MUSIC PERFORMANCE LAB </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">IBS<br>(<a href="mailto:abcder@icom.edu.my">fafafan@icom.edu.my</a>)        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">3 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center">THU<br>      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">1:00PM<br>      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">3:30PM<br>      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">E2<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1126&type=1')">FP102-FIM CS.pdf</a><br /></td>
                  <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=470&type=2')">FP102-Assignment 1 Brief.pdf</a><br />II <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=471&type=2')">FP102-Assignment 2 Brief.pdf</a><br />III <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=788&type=2')">FP102-Peer Assessment Sheet.pdf</a><br /></td>  
      </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=GE030-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">GE030-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">ELECTRONICS & COMPUTER SYSTEMS </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">ZHZ<br>(<a href="mailto:fafafer@gmail.com">abcdef@gmail.com</a>)        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">3 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center">MON<br>WED<br>       </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">7:30PM<br>      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">8:45PM<br>      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">C2<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1203&type=1')">GE030-FIM CS.pdf</a><br /></td>
                  <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=474&type=2')">GE030-Assignment Brief.pdf</a><br />II <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=684&type=2')">GE030-Oral Presentation Brief.pdf</a><br /></td>  
      </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=HM010-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">HM010-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">SURVEY OF POP MUSIC </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">IBS<br>(<a href="mailto:abcdef@icom.edu.my">abcder@icom.edu.my</a>)     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">2 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center">FRI<br>      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">11:00AM<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">12:40PM<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">RH<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1220&type=1')">HM010-FIM CS.pdf</a><br /></td>
                  <td valign="top" align="left"></td>  
      </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=MT010-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">MT010-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">MUSIC TECHNOLOGY & MIDI SYSTEMS </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">SKS<br>(<a href="mailto:faer@icom.edu.my">sdferfs@icom.edu.my</a>)      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">2 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center">TUE<br>THU<br>       </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">12:00PM<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">12:50PM<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">C3<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1131&type=1')">MT010-FIM CS.pdf</a><br /></td>
                  <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=776&type=2')">MT010-Project Brief.pdf</a><br />II <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=775&type=2')">MT010-Assignment Brief.pdf</a><br /></td>  
      </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=PF011-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">PF011-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">PERFORMANCE SEMINAR </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">IBS<br>(<a href="mailto:fafafa@icom.edu.my">fafafaf@icom.edu.my</a>)        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">0 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center"><br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">BY APPT<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">BY APPT<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">BY APPT<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1208&type=1')">PF011-PF031-FIM CS.pdf</a><br /></td>
                  <td valign="top" align="left"></td>  
      </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=PI041-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">PI041-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">VOICE </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">IBS<br>(<a href="mailto:fafafa@icom.edu.my">fafan@icom.edu.my</a>)      </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">1 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center"><br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">BY APPT<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">BY APPT<br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">BY APPT<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1143&type=1')">PI041-FIM CS.pdf</a><br /></td>
                  <td valign="top" align="left">I <a href="#" onclick="return popup('/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=795&type=2')">PI0XX mark sheet.pdf</a><br /></td>  
      </tr>
          <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="100"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return popup2('/icom/student/main/report?varCrs_ID=PL001-001&varSemester_code=1/20&prog_id=FIM')">PL001-001</a></td>
        <td valign="top" width="150">English Placement </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">VNS<br>(<a href="mailto:xxx@gmail.com">abcder@gmail.com</a>)        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">0 </td>
                <td valign="top" width="30" align="center"><br>     </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">-<br>       </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">-<br>       </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100" align="center">-<br></td>
                <td valign="top" align="left"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use regex pattern matching for python

```
import re
path = re.compile("/icom/faculty/viewer/.[a-z]{2}.*")
lst = path.findall(sauce)
print(lst)
```

lst will be a list with all "/icom/faculty/viewer/?id" strings containing the mentioned match are followed by any character until a new line is encountered. 
So...you should get a list of strings which match the string and the unique index=xxx values.

You can iterate over this list and separate further the into smaller lists for each assignment you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you need some logic for string matching.

This is a possible approach to do so.

You check if a string is in another and proceed with your logic, otherwise you can define some excepts.

```
link = "/icom/faculty/viewer/?id=1260&type=2"
word = "/icom/faculty/viewer/?id"

if word in link:
   print('word is in link')
else:
   print('word is not in link')
```

If you refer to string concatenaion I recommend this thread:

[Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Additionally If you want to grab strings of multiple strings you can define a simple for-loop.