# Printing singular/plural depending on dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

```
favorite_languages = {'jen': ['python', 'ruby'], 'sarah': ['c'], 'edward': ['ruby', 'go'],
                  'phil': ['python', 'haskell'],}


for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():

   print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite languages are:")
   for language in languages:print("\t" + language.title())

output:Jen's favorite languages are:
Python
Ruby

Sarah's favorite languages are:
C
enter code here

Edward's favorite languages are:
Ruby
Go

Phil's favorite languages are:
Python
Haskell
```

i want to display "Sarah's favorite language is" instead of are. can not figure it out how to write the if statement to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite language" + 
      ("s are:" if len(languages) > 1 else " is:"))
```

It should then print:

```
Jen's favorite languages are:
    Python
    Ruby

Sarah's favorite language is:
    C

Edward's favorite languages are:
    Ruby
    Go

Phil's favorite languages are:
    Python
    Haskell
```

Not directly related to your question, but using `+` to concatenate strings is frowned upon. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python) for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Current/Best way

```
for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
  print()
  if len(languages) > 1:
    print(f"{name}'s favoutire language are")

else:
    print(f'{name} language is')


for language in languages:
     print(language)
```