# Check if there is a next item on the list to avoid: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I'm searching for a solution

```
I try to get the images from: 
<pics>
<pic>240006.jpg</pic>
<pic>240006_2.jpg</pic>
</pics>
```

Wel with this code:

```
for x in root.iter('product'):
    pics =x.findall('pics/pic')

    images = "https://cdn.edc-internet.nl/800/" + pics[0].text + ";" + "https://cdn.edc-internet.nl/800/" + pics[1].text + ";" + "https://cdn.edc-internet.nl/800/" + pics[2].text
print(images)
```

With some product having 2 images, it creates a "List out of range"
I want to check if there is a value if not the let online see the 2 or even 1 image link.

I have tried it with an if statement That failed, the i had try it with an try: But that gives me only the value with 3 pictures

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote 3 times your link construction code? One easy solution would be to iterate on `pics` and build the URL as you go, reconstructing everything with a `";".join(iterable)` a the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you might not know how many elements you have in `pics`, a better way would be to iterate over it, creating the URLs on the fly. This would avoid using fixed indexes that could, as you see, break if `pics` length is less than 3, and return all of the items if you ended up scraping more than 3.

```py
for x in root.iter('product'):
    pics = x.findall('pics/pic')

    URL = "https://cdn.edc-internet.nl/800/%s"
    images = ";".join(URL % picture for picture in pics)

    print(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
for x in root.iter('product'):
    pics=x.findall('pics/pic')

    for i in range(len(pics)):
        images=images+"https://cdn.edc-internet.nl/800/"+pics[i].text+";"
    print(images)
```

Comment: Joining strings like this should be avoided as it's generally worst-performing than constructing it live. Check my answer below

Comment: Turns out I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python, here they say that using "".join isn't faster than +=, has this changed in python3?

Comment: The difference looks pretty stark to me.
`timeit("';'.join(str_list)", setup="str_list = map(str, range(10_000))") # 0.16372650700213853` vs. `timeit("res = ""; for x in str_list: res += x", setup="str_list = map(str, range(10_000))")  # 0.030358272000739817`

From what I remember, you gain both in raw performance and in RAM usage

Comment: The difference in performance comes from the fact that using `+` will create many strings, one per loop actually (since those are immutable). You would then have something like `(((a+b)+c)+d)`. This would re-read the first item n-1 times, the second, n-2 times, etc