# I coded as follows, why it didn't compile as "my name is Maria, my age is 11." please? Thank you ;)

Tags: python

```
name = "Maria"
age = 11

print(type(name), type(age))
print("my name is 'name', my age is 'age'.")
```

---

```
<class 'str'> <class 'int'>
my name is 'name', my age is 'age'.
```

Comment: Use f strings, to substitute the variables

Comment: Did you have ``f-strings`` in mind? ``print(f"my name is {name}, my age is {age}.")`` notice the leading ``f`` before the double quotes and the curly brackets instead of single quotes.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "string interpolation"; I would recommend taking searching around on how to do that on Python. There are a few variations.

Comment: Or use print("my name is ",name,", my age is ",age,".")

Answer (score 6):

**There are 4 ways I think.**

Using normal addition or String concatenation

```
print('my name is ' + name + ', my age is ' + str(age) + '.')
```

Using f-string

```
print(f'my name is {name}, my age is {age}.')
```

Using `.format()`

```
print("my name is {name}, my age is {age}.".format(name=name, age=age))
```

Using the `%` operator

```
print("my name is %s, my age is %i." % (name, age))
```

Comment: Side note: ``Using normal addition`` is commonly referred to as ``String concatenation``. And you missed the ``%`` operator. Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735266/4349415

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to add quotes for variable to assign its value.

```
print("my name is",name,"my age is",age)
```

Edit: @Wei, yeah I missed to notice it too. You can use the punctuation marks as strings using quotes and concatenate them.
So, it needs to be like this

```
print("My name is",name,",","My age is",age,".")
```

Additionally, `comma` adds a space by default in `concatenation`. Inorder to handle this problem you can use `plus` as concat operator. But keep in mind, you have to convert integers to string using `str()` when you're using `+` in concatenation.

```
print("My name is "+name+","+"My age is "+str(age)+".")
```

Comment: It compiled "my name is Maria my age is 11", what if I want "my name is Maria, my age is 11." like this with punctuation marks please?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work :

```py
name = "Maria"
age = 11

print('my name is ' + name + ', my age is ' + str(age))
```