# Box & Name in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to get this to work? Have a full box and then have the name displayed in the center?

```
users_name = input (str(" Enter Your Name: "))
print("**************************************************")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                  users_name                    *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("*                                                *")
print("**************************************************")
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **f-strings** to replace the users_name in the text. Please see the link below for more details.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

Answer (score 4):

Use a formatting string to center the string in a specified width:

```py
print(f"*{users_name:^48}*")
```

Python Docs:

- [Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)
- [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
- [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Learn a bit here, did not know this existed or was possible