# Python syntax error when using strings in variables

Tags: python-3.x

## Code

```py
import random
    
print("Witaj w grze papier, kamień i nożyczki")
    
player_1 = input("Wpisz nazwę gracza nr 1: ")
player_2 = input("Wpisz nazwę gracza nr 2: ")
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór %s:",% (player_1)))
```

## Problem

This code seems to be causing a syntax error and i dont know why

````
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór %s:",% (player_1)))
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the comma from line 13

```py
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór %s:" % (player_1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Remove the comma after the string
`choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór %s:" % (player_1)))`

### Other cleaner way (imo)

I would recommend you format the string differently, using the `format()` function.

`choice_1 = input("Wpisz wybór {}:".format(player_1))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.6 or a later version, I'd recommend using [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) ([PEP 498 – Literal String Interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)). It would be easy to concatenate strings in Python.

```py
choice_1 = (input(f"Wpisz wybór {player_1}:"))
```

Here are a few alternatives ways that would do the same,

```py
# Concatenating With the + Operator
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór" + player_1 + ":"))

# String Formatting with the % Operator
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór %s:" % (player_1)))

# String Formatting with the { } Operators with str.format()
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór {}:".format(player_1)))
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór {0}:".format(player_1)))
choice_1 = (input("Wpisz wybór {some_name}:".format(some_name=player_1)))
```

You can find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735266/6194097) to learn more ways to concatenate strings in Python.