# How to convert a multiline print into a single string

Tags: python

I have to take multiple numbers and convert them into there corresponding characters based on ASCII. I have gotten the code to the point where it will print the characters multiple times spanning multiple lines 1 character at a time, but I need to combine them.

```py
fname = input("Enter filename: ")
infile = open(fname,'r')
numList = infile.read()
for i in numList.split():
    chr(eval(i))
```

Throwing a print() in front of the chr( in the for loop is what prints it on multiple lines. My question is how do I call on that for loop and turn it into 1 combined string while using:

```py
print(<expression>, end='')
```

an example of the output I am getting is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

and I need to combine it to

```
abcdefg
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to print the result to stdout, or just construct a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-the-preferred-way-to-concatenate-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I am trying to get the result that prints 62 lines of response and makes it one connected string. Instead of a,b,c,d,e etc. printing 1 character per line I want it to take that and combine it into 1 line

Comment: Using `end=''` should also make all characters appear in the same line. It seems you are running different code than you are telling us here.

Comment: That's what I thought to but I can't figure out which expression I need to insert to call on the for loop. Which variable gets called upon? Then, when I try to put the print(chr(eval(I,end=''))) into the for loop I get an error saying chr takes no keyword arguments

Comment: I figured out the error I was making. I was placing the end='' into the wrong set of parenthesis. I needed to connect it to the print statement, not the chr or eval statements.  As soon as I did that it worked. Thank you all for you answers and getting me to think on it more. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

> *"... how do I call on that for loop and turn it into 1 combined string ..."*

Add a local variable above the *for-loop* to append the value.

And, use *[int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)* instead of *[eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)*.

```py
s = ''
for i in numList.split():
    s += chr(int(i))
```

Or, as a *list-comprehension*, with the *[str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)* method.

```py
s = ''.join([chr(int(x)) for x in numList.split()])
```

Alternately, you could use the *[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)* *function*.

```py
s = ''.join(map(chr, map(int, numList.split())))
```